# How to reduce image before I put on my latex document

Tags: includegraphics

I have a similar question to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601359). I want to decrease the image quality, so for example if I have an 18MB image, I want to reduce it first before using `\includegraphics....`.

And yes, I know I can use image resize app to resize the image manually. But I have a problem that my image is presented with no background it some kind of a logo, which is not a square border.  And if I reduce the size of the image using image resize app, the image will have a box on the border which will affect the appearance when I place the logo image on a colored background.

[Image before getting resized](https://ibb.co/PMX1KhJ)

[Image after getting resized](https://ibb.co/xCfTg81)

Is that possible? I mean, i want to reduce it with some codes, so the result would run smoothly. Cz my image is too big and affects on my compilation performance. If i not reduce it, the output will run laggy when i compile the document.

Comment: you should be able to resample it in your image editor while preserving the transparent background

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i've tried that. But didn't work. I use background remover and the edges of the logo are slightly erased.

Comment: that is a question about whatever image editor you are using so not really on topic here. google search for univeritas jember logo  shows lots of much smaller versions including png images with transparent backgrounds of a few hundred K so much smaller than your image so one of those may be a possibility.